# Properly handling unique keys in a hash

Tags: javascript, hash

I realize hashes have unique keys already, but my question is aimed at a particular use case (that I feel may be common) regarding hashes.

I have a google map (v3) on my website. I load a bunch of locations from my database, and throw markers on the map at each location. I had an issue in my application where I was seeing duplicate markers for every location. I decided to add a check at the top of my add marker function, to use a hash of previously placed markers (stored by location).

```js
markers = {};

function addMarker(latlng) {
  if (!markers.hasOwnProperty(latlng)) {
    markers[latlng] = true;
  } else {
    return;
  }

  // do other stuff
}
```

This works, but it *feels* hacky. Adding the unused boolean value to each hash key/pair just doesn't feel right, because it's technically not used... I just need the key half.

Is there another approach to accomplish the same idea?

Comment: It isn't hacky. It's a fairly standard use of that type of data structure.

Comment: Why not store a reference to your markers this way? Seems like that might come in handy. `if (!markers[latlng]) markers[latlng] = new google.maps.Marker(..)`

Comment: That's a good idea @deceze - I just implemented that pattern. As a side note, is checking for an undefined value at a given key `if (!markers[latlng])` the same (result) as checking if the key exists by doing `hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: You could just use an array and `indexOf === -1` instead of an object and hasOwnProperty if you don't want the true value. But storing an actual reference will probably be more useful.

Comment: ES6 has `Set` which may be more appealing for your case. Among other things, it only stores unique values, and it supports `mySet.has(someVal)`.